# Shortcut to switch displays

Tags: shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors

I have 2 displays on my PC - an IDE is open fullscreen in one display and Firefox is open fullscreen in another display.

Since I mostly use the keyboard, it's annoying to have to grab the mouse to switch the focus to Firefox and back to the IDE all the time.

Is there a shortcut I could use to switch the focus to "largest window" on display 2 if focus is somewhere in display 1 and vice versa?

Comment: Now there is a shortcut built-in! Hurray!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Today I got an upvote for this question, so I'm posting my solution I've been all the time using for more than a year and am quite happy with.

Step 1: make bash script (e.g. write it to `~/swap.sh` and make it executable) to set focus to a window that is in the middle of the other display:

```
#!/bin/bash

getwindowat() {
    # move mouse to coordinates provided, get window id beneath it, move mouse back
    eval `xdotool mousemove $1 $2 getmouselocation --shell mousemove restore`
    echo $WINDOW
}

# get active app
active=`xdotool getactivewindow`
# get coordinates of an active app
eval `xdotool getwindowgeometry --shell $active`

# if left border of an app is less than display width
# (e.g. one display is 1920px wide, app has x = 200 - means it's 200px to the right from the left border of left monitor
# if it has x = 1920 or more, it's on the right window), it's on screen 0, and we need to focus to screen 1, otherwise to screen 0
(( $X >= $WIDTH )) && focustoscreen=0 || focustoscreen=1;

# get coordinates of the middle of the screen we want to switch
searchx=$[ ($WIDTH / 2) + $focustoscreen * $WIDTH ]
searchy=$[ $HEIGHT / 2 ]

# get window in that position
window=`getwindowat $searchx $searchy`
# activate it
xdotool windowactivate $window
```

Step 2: add a keyboard shortcut to call this script, I put mine to `Super-Tab`

Step 3: use shortcut to switch displays like a boss

Comment: This helps a lot however the mouse is not  moved to the other screen which, it would be great if it does.

Comment: @samarth You can achieve that by removing the `mousemove restore` from the eval, so that it is "eval \`xdotool mousemove $1 $2 getmouselocation --shell\`"

Comment: I've tried step 1, then running `sh swap.sh`, I get error message: *swap.sh: 17: swap.sh: 288: not found swap.sh: 20: swap.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected*, creating a text file with = as title and nothing  Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou try `bash swap.sh`

Comment: This is helpful; is there a way to detect when a display is rotated?  I have  my left monitor rotated (with `xrandr --rotate`) but xdotool does not use the rotation and I don't know how to detect. If the focus is in the rotated display, i need to use the keystroke twice instead of once.

Answer (score 1):

this repository may help you

https://github.com/Eitol/screen_focus_changer

You place the focus_changer.py left script in a fixed place (/ opt for example) And then add the keybinding / shortcut / hotkey in your settings

python3 /opt/focus_changer.py left # Focus to left

python3 /opt/focus_changer.py right # Focus to right

Comment: Thank you! This works nicely in Gnome 3.36 even using Wayland.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between windows.

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> also remebers which two window you last switched between. If you switch to one window (navigate with the arrow keys), then switch back, just pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> will allow you to jump between them, without any further navigation.

Comment: I want to switch displays in dual-monitor setup, not windows. I have multiple applications open, and I don't want to press alt-tab a lot of times until I reach the one on the other display.

Answer (score 0):

If you like me googled *"keyboard shortcut switch monitors linux"* and found this link... the above answers are not the easiest answers, if you are on a GNOME-based environment.

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> +  or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> +  will switch to the monitor in that direction from the currently focused program.