# How to switch to an external monitor when a laptop lid is closed?

Tags: multiple-monitors, power-management, laptop, screen

There are a lot of similar questions. For example [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333672/how-to-turn-off-laptop-screen-when-lid-is-closed-and-connected-to-external-monit) suggests a complicated solution with hotkeys.

Everything worked fine on Ubuntu 22.04. When I closed a laptop lid, then the laptop screen is turned off and an external montor was still turned on.

But after updating to 22.10 the behaviour was changed. Both screens are turned on. I can move a mouse pointer to the closed screen and windows are opened sometimes on the closed laptop screen. How to turn it off automatically?

I installed `dconf-editor`. The power settings are as follows:

```
lid-close-ac-action = blank
lid-close-suspend-with-extenral-monitor = false
```

All settings in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` are commented out:

```
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
```

What settings should I change?

Comment: You may want to report this as a bug is the only change is an upgrade. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've created a bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1995788 Actually I agree that it seems to be a bug, because the laptop screen should be at least turned off when it's closed.